# How to access webpage with variables in python

Tags: python

I have a project and want to access a url by python. If i have `variable1=1` and `variable2=2`, I want an output to be like this:

```
www.example.com/data.php?variable1=1&variable2=2
```

How do I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: It's a knick-knack, Paddywack, give the frog a loan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use formate operation in python for string.
for example

```
variable1=1
variable1=1
url = 'www.example.com/data.php?variable1={}&variable2={}'.format(variable1,variable1)
```

or if you want to use the url with request then you can make a dict and pass it in request like this way

```
import requests
url = 'http://www.example.com/data.php'
data = {'variable1':'1','variable2':'2'}
r = requests.get(url,data)
```

and it will making request on this url

```
http://www.example.com/data.php?variable1=1&variable2=2
```

Comment: Thankyou very much!! Im sorry for my noob question. Im new to this programming language

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
try:
  from urllib2 import urlopen # python 2
except:
  from urllib.request import urlopen # python 3

vars = ['variable1=1', 'variable2=2']
for i in vars:
  url = 'http://www.example.com/data.php?' + i
  response = urlopen(url)
  html = response.read()
  print(html)
```

The first four lines import some code we can use to make a HTTP request.

Then we create a list of variables named `vars`.

Then we pass each of those variables into a loop; that loop will run once for each item in `vars`.

Next we build the url given the current value in `vars`.

Finally we get the html at that address and print it to the terminal.

Comment: Thankyou very much. I will try this. Im sorry for my noob question because im new in this language.. I dont know the syntax and the commands to use.

Comment: @DarrylBat-og no worries, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try string formatting...

```
url = 'www.example.com/data.php?variable1={}&variable2={}'.format(variable1, variable2)
```

This means the 2 `{}` will be replaced with whatever you pass in `.format()`, which in this case is just the variables' values